# Something Server Specific Not Allowing Connect with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, apache2, centos, facebook-access-token

I had FB connect working perfectly fine on my site.  Then one day, we noticed it was no longer working.  It is not giving any errors, but when I try to do the getUser() function from my facebook class, the response to the send of my signed request is coming back empty, no user data. That is the basic problem, but let me detail what I have nailed down.

I believe there is a problem with the server somehow, either something inside httpd.conf or perhaps php.ini and here is why.

I took all my PHP pages that are required for the FB integration over to another server and another domain. They worked fine.  That, to me, ruled out a problem with the code itself, or the Facebook App settings I am using.

I then went back to the problem server, and setup a 3rd domain and tried the same thing again.   It would not work. So that, to me, ruled out a problem with the specific domain I am ultimately trying to get working again.

I will admit, I dont know what changes may have been made between the time it was working and when it suddenly was not.  If I did, I had a solid idea, I would just roll it back. I did have someone, "recompile apache with mod_deflate and mod_cache."  I tried to search for those causing a problem with FB but didnt find anything.

PHP Version 5.3.10

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 10 2012 20:31:21
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.9.1 rev9999

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my situation.  The key to my solution was going to line 633 of base_facebook.php and going an echo $e; to determine why the token response was failing.  I then managed to identify the root of the problem:

CurlException: 1: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurlCurl

So I contacted my server support people who informed me, "The curl php module has been built without ssl support." which was after they had said

"I am almost positive that when I rebuild apache I made sure curlssl was checked. This is a typical option that people request to have enabled, so I always make sure it is enabled."

So the end solution was that they had to recompile apache and php with the curlssl module.